# Template deduction guide doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Following 'C++ Templates the Complete Guide', I wrote following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Cont = std::vector<T>>
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack() = default;

        Stack(T elem) :
            elems({std::move(elem)})
        { }

        auto push(T const& elem)       -> void;
        auto pop()                     -> void;
        auto top()               const -> T const&;
        auto empty()             const -> bool
        {
            return elems.empty();
        }

    private:
        Cont elems;
};

Stack(char const*) -> Stack<std::string>;

template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto Stack<T, Cont>::push(T const& elem) -> void
{
    elems.push_back(elem);
}

template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto Stack<T, Cont>::pop() -> void
{
    assert(!elems.empty());
    elems.pop_back();
}

template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto Stack<T, Cont>::top() const -> T const&
{
    assert(!elems.empty());
    return elems.back();
}
```

And used template class `Stack` in function `main` as follows:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    Stack stack_string {"hello"};
    std::cout << stack_string.top().size() << std::endl;
}
```

I assumed that due to 'template deduction guide' I provided with, the concrete type was `Stack<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`

But compiler (Visual Studio 15 2017 with C++17) produced error saying that return type of `Stack::top` was `const char *const`

How do I make 'template deduction guide' works with `const char*` type?

Comment: Seems a MSVC bug.

Comment: @xskxzr ok, it looks like many compilers did not implement template deduction guide yet. I guess I should skip this chapter then : (

Comment: At least the latest gcc and clang version can handle this, so you can switch to one of these compilers.

Comment: Yeah, definitely use one of Clang or GCC to learn C++, especially templates. MSVC still has a lot of bugs. Mr STL provides a [really cool cutting-edge MinGW distribution](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) for Windows.

Comment: @xskxzr it works for me with VS 2017 15.8.3, `/std:c++17` flag included (project code [here](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/51760374-template-deduction-guide-doesnt-seem-to-be-working))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least some versions of MSVC require:

```
template<std::size_t N>
Stack(char const(&)[N]) -> Stack<std::string>;
```

as it appears it doesn't "decay" the array into a pointer before doing deduction guides.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/pOhFCT).